# What is trip-off current and time

Tags: mosfet, current, current-measurement

I just encounter the notion of trip-off current and timing in an electrical document. This document is not available online but i'll try to describe it hereafter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7MX46.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(schema from the documentation)

According to the documentation, the mosfet can drive 2A nominal with a 2.4A trip-off current and a trip-off timing of 10ms. Does it mean that the drive 2A at anytime and 2.4A for a period of 10ms? Once this delay elapse, the control switch off the mosfet to not damage the load?

Comment: No, that won't work. The body diode in the MOSFET is incorrectly polarized. Show a picture of the off-line document circuit instead. Neither is there anything that senses current to trip the MOSFET (should it have been placed correctly) in order to turn-off the MOSFET. Bad circuit and who can tell what this 10 ms timing is all about with what you have drawn?

Comment: @Andyaka I'll take a picture of the schema later, I can't do it right now. I'm looking for the general concept of trip-off current.

Comment: Appart from the bad drawing, but good try anyway, you are basically correct. The trip-off is the safety limit, the time is how long it takes for the thing to open the switch thereafter.

Comment: Protection devices often have a bit of a grey zone, so it is possible that the documentation means the circuit will definitely be on with 2A or less, definitely trip off with 2.4A, and in between in is undetermined. The trip off is probably the maximum time before shut down. Here is a very different, much lower current, device that does the same thing: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4914B-MAX4917B.pdf